# Text-transform:uppercase equivalent in Android?

Tags: android

Does this exist? I need to make a TextView which is always uppercase.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I don't see anything like this in the TextView attributes. However, you could just make the text uppercase before setting it:

```
textView.setText(text.toUpperCase());
```

If the TextView is an EditText and you want whatever the user types to be uppercase, you could implement a TextWatcher and use the EditText addTextChangedListener to add it, and on the onTextChange method take the user input and replace it with the same text in uppercase.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(upperCaseTextWatcher);

final TextWatcher upperCaseTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        editText.setText(editText.getText().toString().toUpperCase());
        editText.setSelection(editText.getText().toString().length());
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    }
};
```

Comment: That works if `text` is a String. If you're getting the String from your xml files using `R.string.someID`, then you'll need to throw in a `Resources.getString` call (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getString%28int%29)

Comment: I was afraid I'd have to do it this way. Was hoping there'd be a simple attribute I was missing.

Comment: Won't this be creating a stackOverFlow?

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Please refer to Lars answer: you can do it with the `textAllCaps` attribute.

Comment: Calling `editText.setText()` inside the textChanged listener will cause an infinite loop. At least it did for me without removing then re-adding the TextWatcher.

Comment: Is this answer outdated? `android:textAllCaps="true" ` seems to work for me [see answers below]

Answer (score 121):

Try this:

```
   <TextView 
            android:textAllCaps="true"
    />
```

Comment: `android:textAllCaps` only works if your minSdkVersion >= 14 (Ice Cream Sandwich)

Comment: I know it's for a comment from 3+ years ago, but this only works if you're using the on-screen keyboard - if someone has a physical keyboard (bluetooth or on device) then it's ignored, it's better to use a listener

Answer (score 31):

For your EditText you can use InputFilter.AllCaps as filter

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.AllCaps()});
```

See: 
http://d.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.AllCaps.html

Also you can specify your EditText via `android:inputType`:

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:inputType="textCapCharacters" />
```

Comment: the filter worked perfectly thanks a lot. however I wouldnt recommend using the inputType "textCapCharacters" since its deprecated.

Comment: @Raykud where did you see that `textCapCharacters` is deprecated ?

Comment: i know i am commenting very late, but once all the characters are capitalized is there something like that InputFilter.Allsmallcharacters?

Answer (score 15):

use

```
android:textAllCaps="true"
```

this will make your all `Textview` capital.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it, only adding TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS to InputType::

```
editText.setInputType(android.text.InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
                   + android.text.InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS);
```

I hope be helped!

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3acapitalize) at android developers guide:

```
<TextView 
...
android:capitalize="characters"
...
/>
```

Comment: This only applies to EditText, not TextView. From the documentation: "[...] automatically capitalize what the user types"

Comment: Real answer ?? huh .... "android:capitalize is deprecated: Use inputType instead"