# How to force uppercase to the whole app through themes?

Tags: android

In my app, I'm using a custom font that needs all texts in uppercase to render correctly on screen.

Strings in strings.xml are in lowercase, but I need to keep them that way in case I use a different font in the future, so rewriting them in uppercase is not an option.

Is there a way to force the app to render all texts in uppercase using a global theme attribute?

(I tried setting the `textAllCaps` attribute in the theme, but it doesn't work).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to style a TextView to uppercase all of its letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434588/is-there-a-way-to-style-a-textview-to-uppercase-all-of-its-letters)

Comment: @Ars_Codicis Unfortunately, it's not enough. That only allows me to change my own text views, but I need to set uppercase to all other texts like preferences, dialogs, snackbars, tooltips, etc

Comment: Ah. I see... :)