# How To capitalize the letters in AutoCompleteTextView dynamically?

Tags: android, autocomplete

I am developing the application which consists of `AutoCompleteTextView`,here is my problem,How I can upper case the letters entering in `AutoCompleteTextView`.

1. I Don't want in xml: `android:capitalize="characters"`
2. I want to declare in Java code.

Comment: well, capitalize in xml is like setting a keylistener, so you need to programme a keylistener that implements this if you want it in java. there are many similar questions here on SO

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text-transform:uppercase equivalent in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286343/text-transformuppercase-equivalent-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this..In your text watcher in ontextchanged change the text to upper case..and check if the new string in edittext is the old string which you converted to upper case...in order to avoid stackoverflow error..

```
 String upper = mytextview.getText().toString().toUpperCase()
 mytextview.setText(upper);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code there are some other flags also which you can check and try.

```
tv.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS);
```