# Set upper case for TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have TextView. I would like to show text in upper case mode. 
Is there attributed for upper case? 
Just I have text in strings.xml and I need use the line in several place as lower case and upper case.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Use `String` class method while setting the text to `TextView` as

```
tv.setText(strings.toUpperCase());
```

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3286343/593709) post for detail discussion.

**EDIT:** This was answered way back before API 14. As other answer mentioned here, `textView.isAllCaps = true` and its java methods were introduced from `TextView`. Please use those.

Answer (score 102):

In the layout XML, you can set the **[`android:textAllCaps`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textAllCaps)** attribute on your `TextView`:

```
<TextView android:textAllCaps="true"></TextView>
```

Answer (score 29):

use this for programatically like `textView.setAllCaps(false)` for as it is and `textView.setAllCaps(true)`for Uppercase
`android:textAllCaps="true"` for XML Layout

Comment: but this works from API 14 and above.. does not work for API level below 14, any solution ?

Answer (score 12):

Kotlin:

```
textView.isAllCaps = true
```

Comment: Since `TextView` doesn't have a getter for all caps, Kotlin doesn't make a property available to you, you still need to call `setAllCaps(true)`.

Comment: Weird thing to observe and only because of that I am looking over internet. I am able to use `TextView#isAllCaps` but it's giving lint error on QA's system and making him to change to `TextView#setAllCaps()`. But giving me lint warning for that

Comment: Ok got it. API version for `maxSdkVersion` less than 28 will give the lint error for `TextView#isAllCaps`. 28 and above will work smooethly

Answer (score 9):

For an XML approach, you don't want to use `android:capitalize` because this is intended for use during text input. Instead, use [textAllCaps](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textAllCaps). If your strings are declared as lower case, then it is quite simple to toggle between upper and lower case on a per-TextView basis.

Comment: I like this approach, but just as a warning this is only available from API 14 onwards.

Comment: @kcoppock Ah, I was unaware of this. Hopefully it's useful to someone, though.

Answer (score 9):

use it

```
<TextView android:textAllCaps="true"></TextView>
```

Answer (score 6):

I believe there is no such attribute, but you can use

```
textView.setText(text.toUpperCase());
```

also found this, never tested by myself though

```
android:capitalize="characters"
```

Comment: Do not use `android:capitalize="characters"` in `TextView`

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

**Upper Case**

```
textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name).toUpperCase());
```

**Lower Case**

```
textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name).toLowerCase());
```

Answer (score 3):

Set android:textAllCaps="true" in layout file.

Edit :
If you are using kotlin use .capliatlized() method
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/capitalize.html

Answer (score 2):

You could create a custom view derived from TextView and override the setText method to capitalize.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that easily in android xml file.
you should add this line to TextView.

```
 <TextView 
      android:textAllCaps="true"/>
```

if you want to do that in code, you can do like this :

```
        textView.setText(strings.toUpperCase());
```

Answer (score 1):

Get a reference for your TextView and call this method on the object

```
    textView.setAllCaps(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Java

```
textView.setAllCaps(true)
```

Kotlin

```
textView.isAllCaps = true
```