# Set editText text to upper case on addTextChangedListener making app hang

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-edittext

I want to make upper case even if the user write lowercase in `edittext`.So I am setting `ediText` text to upper case on `addTextChangedListener` as per below.

```
  editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher{
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s : CharSequence?, start : Int, count : Int, after : Int) {
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s : CharSequence?, start : Int, before : Int, count : Int) {
                    editText.setText(s.toString().toUpperCase())
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(s : Editable?) {

            }
    })
```

But doing this when I type something in `editText`, app is hanging and I have to kill the app and restart it again.As I want to use this in binding adapter I can't use AllCaps method of xml

Comment: Why dont you use [InputType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:inputType) method and assign textCapCharacters to it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to capitalize every letter in an Android EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705776/how-to-capitalize-every-letter-in-an-android-edittext)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I see that you've got a solid problem statement in your question, but your question still needs a few changes if you want to get an answer. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `textwatcher` before editing the text of the `EditText` and readd it again when the change is done.

```
    val watcher: TextWatcher = object : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            editText.removeTextChangedListener(this)
            editText.setText(s.toString().toUpperCase())
            editText.addTextChangedListener(this)
        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {}
    }

    editText.addTextChangedListener(watcher)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Input type in your xml or programmatically.

```
editText.inputType == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS
```

In your xml you can put

```
android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
```

This solution will automatically turn the input to UperCase

Comment: Yes but I want to add this method in binding adapter