# Android KeyboardView capital letters

Tags: android, keyboard

I made custom keyboardview in Android. I used to this in my application where I don't want to use any other keyboard. Soft keyboard is hide. I can't get capital letters from keyboard. Have you got any idea how can I get capital letter in my editview?

BasicOnKeyboardActionListener

```
 @Override
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {

    long eventTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(eventTime, eventTime,
            KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, primaryCode, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            KeyEvent.FLAG_SOFT_KEYBOARD | KeyEvent.FLAG_KEEP_TOUCH_MODE);
    mTargetActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
```

I have tried check capital letter with event.isCapsLockOn() and event.isShiftPressed(), but without success. For capslock I used to 115 code, but for shift 59 code in xml for keyboard.

I look forward to receiving your reply.
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the toUpperCase function for that.

You can also refer following link for the same.
[Text-transform:uppercase equivalent in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286343/text-transformuppercase-equivalent-in-android)

Comment: You are right, but I would like to have an opportunity to change size letter between capital letter and non-capital letter from keyboardview.

Answer (score 0):

In your onKey handler, you'll need to know if "shift" has been clicked. You could do something like:

```
case Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT:
            shifted = !shifted;
            keyboardView.setShifted(shifted);
            keyboardView.invalidateAllKeys();
            break;
```

Where "shifted" is a field in your listener. This field can be used when you handle key presses for other keys, for example your default onKey implementation could be:

```
char code = (char) primaryCode;
if (Character.isLetter(code) && shofted) {
    code = Character.toUpperCase(code);
}
commitText(String.valueOf(code), 1);
```

If your listener extends something like BaseInputConnection then you override getEditable to return the editText you're bound to and you get convenient methods like commitText and deleteSurroundingText.

Check out http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm for a really nice overview of this sort of behavior.